# Average "Conversion rate" percentage

Tags: average, percentage, looker-studio, rate

Problem you have encountered:
Cumulative conversion rates for "week" and "month" durations compared with "day" and "week" durations

Steps to reproduce:
Smoothed curve graphics > Dimension: date / Metric: Conversion rate per user > Sort by Date

What you expected to happen:
An average percentage of the averages of the previous durations.
Ex: Average percentage per week based on the daily percentages for that week.